# how to stop compiler from reading unitialized objects as errors

Tags: java, object, null

I have eclipse, and when I try to see if an uninitialized object equals null, it won't let me, it comes up with a "x might not have been intialized" error and I know it should work.

example of what I mean:

```
      Object obj;
      System.out.println(obj==null ? "no value":"has a value");
```

it would not compile and it would say 'obj might not have been initialized' How can I change my compiler settings in eclipse to fix this?

Comment: Fields, variables that sit in the class definition, are initialized to null or 0 or whatever the default value for the type is. local variables that are defined in methods are not initialized to a default value. Being null is not the same as being uninitialized.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I change my compiler settings in eclipse to fix this?

You can't.  The Java language specification *requires* any conformant Java compiler to treat this as a compilation error.

There is no Eclipse compiler setting to cause it to break this rule.

Even (hypothetically) if there was such a setting, I *think* that the bytecode file would fail verification when the JVM attempted to load it.  (If you could somehow trick the JVM into using the value of an uninitialized local variable, that would undermine runtime type security, leading to JVM crashes ... and worse.)

---

If `obj` was an instance variable rather than a local variable, it would be *default initialized* to `null` and you wouldn't get a compilation error.  But local variables are not default initialized.

Answer (score 2):

You don't change the compiler settings in eclipse to fix this: you just initialize the variable `obj`.

```
      Object obj = null;
      System.out.println(obj==null ? "no value":"has a value");
```

From the [Java Specification 4.12.5 - Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> A local variable (§14.4, §14.14) must be explicitly given a value before it is used, by either initialization (§14.4) or assignment (§15.26), in a way that can be verified using the rules for definite assignment (§16).

If you're really bent on not initializing `obj` you need to make it a member of a class instead of a local variable. Then it will have a default initial value: (again, refer to [Java Specification 4.12.5 - Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5))

```
public class Example {

    private static Object obj;

    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(obj==null ? "no value":"has a value");
    }

}
```

... but under the hood it's still getting initialized.

Comment: Alright thanks. Idk for some reason I thought objects in java were null without being initialized. I do it like that anyway, but I keep on hearing that I shouldn't need obj = null. So thanks for reassuring me.

Comment: For variables which are a member of a class (either static or instance variables) they are initialized with a value of `null`. Local variables must be initialized. I linked to the specification, if you want to read more.

Answer (score 1):

That's a local variable, you need to initialise it with:

```
Object obj = null;
```

While certain fields of classes and objects, and arrays, may be implicitly initialised to useful defaults, that is not the case for local variables.

Section `16.2.4` (`Local variable declaration statements`) of `JLS7` is the section to read if you want to understand this but it will take some time to understand, it's pretty obtuse :-)

You'd probably want to start at the top of section `16` (`Definite Assignment`) and work through from there. The first part of that has two paragraphs which are most pertinent here (my italics for emphasis):

> For every access of a local variable or blank `final` field `X`, `X` *must* be definitely assigned before the access, or a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Such an assignment is defined to occur *if and only if* either the simple name of the
>   variable (or, for a field, its simple name qualified by `this`) occurs on the left hand
>   side of an assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

**The compiler shows error because the rule is that all local variables must be initialized before they are first read. So first declare local variable without initializing it, initialize it later, and then use it:**

```
Object obj = null;

 System.out.println(obj==null ? "no value":"has a value");
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change my compiler settings in eclipse to fix this?

The solution is to fix your code.  The purpose of this error is to detect and prevent bugs.  Taking steps to allow broken code to compile is usually a very bad idea.